# SLD one layer with several feature types

Tags: wms, sld, deegree

I wrote an SLD for a layer that contains two feature types: `us-net-sw:SewerPipe`and `us-net-common:Appurtenance`. My WMS - implemented with deegree - only renders `us-net-sw:SewerPipe`. I don't know if my sld is correct, I'm trying to define one layer with two FeatureTypeStyle. If I remove the `us-net-sw:SewerPipe` FeatureTypeStyle deegree renders the `us-net-common:Appurtenance`.

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<sld:StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:app="http://www.deegree.org/app" xmlns:us-net-sw="http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/us-net-sw/4.0" xmlns:deegreeogc="http://www.deegree.org/ogc" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:us-net-common="http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/us-net-common/4.0" xmlns:sed="http://www.deegree.org/se" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:se="http://www.opengis.net/se" xmlns:net="http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/net/4.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.1.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd">
    <sld:NamedLayer>
        <se:Name>US.SewerNetwork</se:Name>
        <sld:UserStyle>
            <sld:IsDefault>1</sld:IsDefault>
            <se:FeatureTypeStyle>
                <se:FeatureTypeName>us-net-sw:SewerPipe</se:FeatureTypeName>
                <se:Rule>
                    <se:LineSymbolizer>
                        <se:Geometry>
                            <ogc:PropertyName>net:link/us-net-common:UtilityLink/net:centrelineGeometry </ogc:PropertyName>
                        </se:Geometry>
                        <se:Stroke>
                            <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#000000</se:SvgParameter>
                            <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
                        </se:Stroke>
                    </se:LineSymbolizer>
                </se:Rule>
            </se:FeatureTypeStyle>
            <se:FeatureTypeStyle>
                <se:FeatureTypeName>us-net-common:Appurtenance</se:FeatureTypeName>
                <se:Rule>
                    <se:PointSymbolizer>
                        <se:Geometry>
                            <ogc:PropertyName>net:geometry</ogc:PropertyName>
                        </se:Geometry>
                        <se:Graphic>
                            <se:Mark>
                                <se:WellKnownName>square</se:WellKnownName>
                                <se:Fill>
                                    <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#808080</se:SvgParameter>
                                </se:Fill>
                                <se:Stroke>
                                    <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#000000</se:SvgParameter>
                                    <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
                                </se:Stroke>
                            </se:Mark>
                            <se:Size>5</se:Size>
                        </se:Graphic>
                    </se:PointSymbolizer>
                </se:Rule>
            </se:FeatureTypeStyle>
        </sld:UserStyle>
    </sld:NamedLayer>
</sld:StyledLayerDescriptor>`

Answer (score 1):

Using two FeatureTypeStyles in one layer is currently not supported by deegree. You could either use multiple symbolizers in case your geometries can be requested using a single feature type (eg. if the other geometry is contained within a subfeature) or just use two layers. You can group multiple layers in the configuration and make only one visible using the theming approach:

http://download.deegree.org/documentation/3.3.15/html/themes.html#standard-themes